# SQL Server 2019 CU11 Express - user DBs started up 45 mins after server restart - when scheduled backups connected to them - not auto_close issue

Tags: sql-server-2019

This happened yesterday after server restart.  The system DBs started at 9:44AM - user DBs started at 10:35AM.  (Starting up database: OraDocumentum) User DBs started because Netbackup tried to connect to them to perform scheduled backup - then DBs started up.  So Netbackup errored and alerted first time it tried to connect to them as DBs were trying to quickly start - which is why I found this issue.  I've read in old articles that express user DBs are set by default to "AUTO_START" = "true".   But my params for them are set to "false".  So that doesn't explain it.

Comment: Adding screen shot of SQL log file:

Comment: do you have alwayson ag in place?

Comment: SQL Server 2019 express edition - so no AGs